# Is there a standard for exceptions handling ? If yes, kindly provide a link

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm developing in a code block has been written by a previous developer, he did not like handling exceptions at all!

I wonder if I could found any guideline about exception handling in general.

For example: Assuming there is a method responsible for executing a query in database, if it fails in the connection then should it throws the same exception to the caller? or it should just handle it and log it and returns `false` (means failed).

I know that the question seems to be subjective, I just want any resources, guideline or standard for exception handling.

Regards.

Comment: try this [Good Exception Management Rules Of Thumb] http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GoodExceptionManagementRulesOfThumbBackToBasicsEdition.aspx

Comment: What sort of app is this? WinForms? ASP.NET?

Comment: @Justin E. Morgan: Web Service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ask 10 developers, you're likely to get 10 different answers. A general rule of thumb I live by is that exception handling should be standardized and not repeated in every single method. I try to strive for exceptions to be handled once per layer in a consistent manner.

So in a standard 3 layer architecture (presentation, business, data), you would have a standard exception handling mechanism at each layer, and all three of those mechanisms would behind the scenes call the same logging/notification/etc.

Here is a link to [Microsoft's Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Exception handling is a 'concern' as in Separation of Concerns and as such it should not be sprinkled around your application and mixed in with your core business logic. It's an area that will likely evolve at a different pace than your business logic.

For example you mentioned opening a database connection. You might start off by logging the exception, but later on you might determine that it should auto retry on timeout, or send an alert or maybe it would be appropriate to implement the [Circuit Breaker Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern).

Adhering to the single responsibility principle and separation of concerns enable you to independently evolve your exception handling behavior. Consider this interface:

```
public interface IConnectionFactory
{
    IConnection Create();
}
```

If you do not do any exception handling in your base implementation, that allows you use inheritance, the decorator pattern or some facility of your framework to add additional behavior.

```
public class RetryOnTimeoutConnectionFactory { ... }
public class CircuitBreakerConnectionFactory { ... }
```

The other thing to consider is context. You mentioned this is web service. Well if you are following REST semantics, you would probably translate your exceptions into HTTP status codes depending on the classification of the exception. If you trap your exceptions at a low level and silently return `false` then you really handcuff yourself.